# Apps script google.visualization.xx is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api

I have an App Script to draw a chart using google.visualization.Dashboard.

This is the part where the code is stopping:

```
     try {
        var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));
        //var test= new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));
    }
    catch(err) {
        document.getElementById("dashboard_div").innerHTML = err.message;
    }
```

It worked for a year and until today but now, following error appears using the try/catch:

> google.visualization.Dashboard is not a constructor

As you can see in the commented line, google.visualization.Table is not working too.

I didn't see any changes in the documentations [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataview-class) and [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls) and the related issues are too old and not representative of my error.

Does anyone have the same error?

Answer (score 0):

The error was about the loader code:

Old code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {'packages':['corechart', 'table', 'gauge', 'controls']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
</script>
```

New one:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'table', 'gauge', 'controls']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
</script>
```

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#update-library-loader-code)